# How to inject classes into Application class using Hilt?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am trying to onboard Hilt in my android application.

My setup currently looks like this:

Application in App Gradle Module:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
public class App extends Application {

@Inject DatabaseDriver driver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    driver.initialize(this);
   }
}
```

My interface in App Gradle Module:

```
@Singleton
public interface DatabaseDriver {
   void initialize(Context context);
}
```

Then I have an implementation to **DatabaseDriver** in my Database Gradle Module where the Hilt module is also declared.

**ParseDatabaseDriver**:

```
@Singleton
class ParseDatabaseDriver : DatabaseDriver {
    override fun initialize(context: Context) {

       registerSubClasses2()

       Parse.initialize(
           Parse.Configuration.Builder(context)
               .applicationId(context.getString(R.string.server_app_id))
            .clientKey(context.getString(R.string.server_client_key))
            .server(context.getString(R.string.server_url))
            .build()
    )

    val parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
    val parseACL = if (parseUser == null) ParseACL() else ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
    parseACL.publicReadAccess = true
    parseACL.publicWriteAccess = true
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(parseACL, true)

    if (parseUser != null) ParseUser.getCurrentUser().acl = parseACL
   }
}
```

**Hilt Module**:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface ParseDatabaseDriverModule {
   @Binds
   fun bindsDatabaseDriver(databaseDriverImpl: ParseDatabaseDriver): DatabaseDriver
}
```

When trying to build this I get the following **error**:

*DatabaseDriver cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method*

The bindings seemed to work when I moved what I needed into the same Gradle Module, but I do not want to do that since I am trying to separate domain from persistance layer.

I am not sure what to do..

Please note that the App Module is written in Java and the DB module is written in Kotlin.

Comment: could you share ParseDatabaseDriver class

Comment: I edited to include the ParseDatabaseDriver implementation

Comment: `class ParseDatabaseDriver @Inject constructor() : DatabaseDriver { ... }` - add the `@Inject` annotation to your concrete `DatabaseDriver` class? Also `@Singleton` on your interface does nothing.  Also you don't even need DI for this - you aren't injecting anything .. `object ParseDatabaseDriver : DatabaseDriver { ... }` would work fine ..

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. @MarkKeen , 

I am not trying to inject anything into ParseDatabaseDriver.

I am trying to bind my ParseDatabaseDriver to my interface DatabaseDriver that is injected into my App.java class.

Comment: "This doesn't really answer my question" - I just gave you the answer in the first sentence of my original comment?  The rest was suggestions, which as its a comment I feel I'm fine to add.